# USB C standard insertion depth?

Tags: usb-c

I'm doing a board layout that involves a GCT_USB4110-GF-A USB receptacle. I need to accurately place the receptacle on the board so that when a user plugs in a USB-C cable, the plastic part of the cable is flush with the outside of the case of my product.

I've had a look online and I haven't been able to find any information on the standard insertion depth for USB-C receptacles or plugs. Unfortunately there is no info on any datasheets I could find either.

All of the USB-C devices I own seem to have about 1.5-2.5mm of casing plastic between the plug and the outermost edge of the socket. I'm wondering is there a standard figure for this? How thick can the wall of the casing of my product be and how close to the outer edge must the receptacle be placed?

Comment: The mechanical specs and dimensions are in the USB Type C connector and cable assembly compliance document, which is free for anyone to read. So approved connectors are within the abovementioned specs. But most likely cheap cables are not approved so they may not be compliant so they may not fit.

Comment: Searching this document for distance measurements (search string "mm") yielded no mention of insertion depth anywhere. Do you know what page it is on?
https://www.usb.org/sites/default/files/USB_Type-C_Compliance_Document_rev_1_2.pdf

Comment: Of course not, as there is no "mm" but "millimeter". In case you have not noticed yet, the table of contents does say that whole appendix B contains the critical dimensions.

Answer (score 2):

The [drawing](https://gct.co/files/drawings/usb4110.pdf) seems to contain the number you want:
[image: mating of connector]
You're lucky- quite a few USB-C receptacles I've seen don't specify this, so you just have to eyeball it (perhaps why so many connectors you've seen stick out a bit)

Answer (score 0):

From what I can gather, it seems like the outer surface of the case needs to be 6.2mm from the deepest part of the socket. From the *USB Type C connector and cable assembly compliance document* page 51:

> The continuity test fixture shall provide a planar surface on the mating side located 6.20 ± 0.20 mm from the receptacle Datum A, perpendicular to the direction of insertion.

However this document seems to be concerned mainly with test setups for USB-C so I am yet to get an authorative answer on this.

Answer (score 0):

From the specs, the reference plug length is 6.65mm +/- 0.10mm and the reference receptacle depth is 6.20mm, so based on that, the receptacle should not be recessed more than 0.35mm into the case. However due to mechanical tolerances manufacturing PCBs, mounting PCBs in the case, and how the component aligns itself on PCB during reflow, perhaps it is a good idea to have the componet aligned as you suggest, having the mating side located 6.2mm within the case.